# Concatenate hash value when hash is referenced

Tags: perl

This is my code:

```
my $hash = shift; // in this hash i have a key 'key' that has the value 'this is a'


$hash{'key'} .= 'string'; //trying to concatenate the two strings

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper $hash{'key'}; // prints "hash(0x36fc12..) string"
```

I am trying to get :

```
key=>'this is a string'
```

Comment: That should work. Why isn't it? What errors do you get? What happens if you `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash`?

Comment: That works just fine.  If you're not seeing your desired results, it's because you have an error elsewhere in your script and you've misidentified the problem area.  Please create and post a short and complete script that demonstrates the issue you're having.

Comment: (also, there are no references anywhere in this example.  It's helpful to use the correct terminology.  `key` is simply a key of the hash, and `'this is a'` is the hash's value.  Nothing is referenced.)

Comment: The result is "HASH(0xaw93) string".

Comment: No it's not.  Not with the code you posted.  Post a short and complete script that you are running to generate that result.

Comment: Are you `print`ing it at all? Right now you are just changing a value.

Comment: I edited the question text, i hope it's ok now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use the following!!!

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
```

It would have pointed out your error.

You modify the hash `%hash`, but there is no such hash! You want to modify the hash referenced by `$hash`, so you want

```
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

sub f {
   my $hash = shift;
   $hash->{key} .= ' string';
}

my %hash = ( key => 'this is a' );
f(\%hash);
print(Dumper(\%hash));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are presumably inside a subroutine and you are picking up a hash REFERENCE, not a hash. You need to dereference it like this:

```
%{$hashref}   # dereferenced hashref (just like a hash)

${$hashref}{key}  # access your key (just like a hash)
```

or:

```
$hashref->{key}  # access your key, shorthand style
```

Note the arrow in the shorthand version!

For more information, check out:

```
perldoc perlreftut # MJD's references tutorial
```

(available on the web at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)